# How to make pairs of nodes using filtering in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame in Spark and Scala:

```
nodeId  typeFrom    typeTo     date
1       A           G          2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z
2       B           A          2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z
3       A           B          2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z
4       D           C          2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z
5       G           D          2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z
```

I want to make pairs of `nodeId` for those cases when `typeFrom` and `typeTo` values are the same.

The expected output for the above-shown example is the following one:

```
nodeId_1   nodeId_2   type    date
1          2          A       2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z
3          2          A       2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z
2          3          B       2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z
4          5          C       2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z
5          1          G       2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z
```

I don't know how to make pairs of `nodeId`:

```
df.
  .filter($"typeFrom" === $"typeTo")
  .???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self-join on matching `nodeFrom` with `nodeTo`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "A", "G", "2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z"),
  (2, "B", "A", "2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z"),
  (3, "A", "B", "2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z"),
  (4, "D", "C", "2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z"),
  (5, "G", "D", "2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z")
).toDF("nodeId", "typeFrom", "typeTo", "date")

df.as("df1").join(
  df.as("df2"),
  $"df1.typeFrom" === $"df2.typeTo"
).select(
  $"df1.nodeId".as("nodeId_1"), $"df2.nodeId".as("nodeId_2"), $"df1.typeFrom".as("type"), $"df1.date"
).show(truncate=false)

// +--------+--------+----+------------------------+
// |nodeId_1|nodeId_2|type|date                    |
// +--------+--------+----+------------------------+
// |1       |2       |A   |2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z|
// |2       |3       |B   |2016-10-12T12:00:00.000Z|
// |3       |2       |A   |2016-10-12T12:05:00.000Z|
// |4       |5       |D   |2016-10-12T12:30:00.000Z|
// |5       |1       |G   |2016-10-12T12:35:00.000Z|
// +--------+--------+----+------------------------+
```